# How to make link_to recover soft deleted Items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, acts-as-paranoid

I'm using Rails 4.2 an also using [ActsAsParanoid](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) gem to soft delete items from database.

I've created a controller action to index `.only_deleted` objects...

**sample_controller.rb**

```
  class FlavorsController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def inactive
      @flavors = Flavor.only_deleted
      render action: :index
    end
    ...
   end
```

I'm using a partial `_flavor` to render **Flavor's**, And I wonder how to make `link_to` view helpers to restore this object? Something like...

```
  <%= link_to "Recover", flavor.recover %>
```

Comment: you already have most of your answer, Perhaps you only need to add a new action to your `flavors` controller, something like `def recover`, and in that action, just do `@flavor.recover`. You would also need to add a new member route for that new action, and in that action you would need to load the `@flavor`. Then, just use the added route in your `link_to`.

Comment: @fanta would you please answer with more details, as I've done as you said but it returns error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FlavorsController#recover   Couldn't find Flavor with 'id'=1 [WHERE "flavors"."deleted_at" IS NULL]`

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the `with_deleted` scope on your query. Like `Flavor.with_deleted.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: @messanjah No It's not missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to fanta's comment, I could find the answer...

**1st add member to my routes**

```
  resources :flavors
    collection do
      get 'inactive'
    end
    member do
      get 'recover'
    end
  end
```

**Then in my inactive_index.html.erb** I added the link below

```
  <%= link_to recover_flavor_path(flavor) %>
```